# Rendering multiple-value field in Views theme tpl using arbitrary formatter

Tags: 7, views, entities

I need to merge items of one file field with other file fields, into one  list, as in

```
 <li> Field A File </li>
 <li> Field B File </li>
 <li> Field C0 File </li>
 <li> Field C1 File </li>
 <li> Field C2 File </li>
```

While files A and B are easily formatted in the Views UI (using my custom formatter), the files C have to be formatted in the code of the tpl file. That's because rewriting the output as in `<li>[field_c]</li>` did not work as expected.

So I created a row-style tpl file and when it came to the Field C, the trouble began. I don't seem to be able to invoke my custom formatter by code:

```
  $fitems = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_c');
  $display = array('type' => 'fileformatter', 'settings' => array('link_text' => 'MY CUSTOM FORMATTER STRING'));
  foreach($fitems as $delta => $fitem){
    $output = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_c', $fitems[$delta], $display);
    print '<li>' . render($output) . '</li>';
  }
```

The files from field C are formatted using the default, generic file formatter.
General question arises: CAN custom formatter be invoked by Views tpl file?
The formatter works ok for any other instances, just not here. (It is not themeable yet, if that's of any importance).

I have also checked out this line:
$output = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_c', $display); 
which - to my knowledge - invokes the formmater's `hook_field_formatter_view`, but it does not accept delta :(

What else could I try?

Comment: field_view_field is not what you're looking for, try field_view_value http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_value/7

Comment: field_view_value is excatly what I've been trying without success - please see the code snippet above.